# What's Ubuntu's app development IDE?

Tags: programming, development, qml, ide

1. What's Ubuntu's official IDE used to develop applications?
2. Which language is preferred for Ubuntu apps?

Answer (score 3):

> What's Ubuntu's official IDE used to develop applications?

Qt Creator, Eclipse, MonoDevelop.

- [Reference](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/ides/)

> Which language is preferred for Ubuntu apps?

QML, HTML5, C++.

- [Reference](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answers to your question are both "none"... ubuntu has no official IDE and no preffered language for apps. And that is actually expected to be so: Preferred IDE and language is a matter of what you want/need to do and your personal tastes, rather than the OS you're on.

That said, I suggest you try to start developing with no IDE at all... use a text editor of your choice and compile by command-line. That will help you understand exactly how your IDE is helping you whenever you use one (I'm assuming you're about to start programming).

As for the programming language, I use Python for quick tasks, because it's a really easy to use and intuitive language. For more complex tasks I use C++. But that's because I have more experience with C++ than Python. AFAIK you can do almost anything with Python too.

There's also the GUI issue, and I believe the major native alternatives are [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) and [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) (and maybe [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/)). I have not much to tell you here, because I have no experience with GUI on Linux, but from what I read, it seems like a matter of taste too.